# Javascript alert not displaying diacritics in a php contact form

Tags: php, javascript, alert, contact-form

Found this simple contact form on the internet. Everything is ok, but the alert can't seem to display some characters that are specific for my language like ā ē š ž ī ļ.
Here is the code of the contact form:

```
if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Jūsu ziņa ir saņemta!');
    window.location = '/';
</script>
<?php
}
```

Here is how the alert gets displayed.

[image]

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `<script language="javascript" charset="UTF-8">`?

Comment: then send in PHP `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')` before you output a template

Comment: Where exactly in the code should I insert this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Unicode escapes where ASCII won't do:

```js
alert("J\u016bsu zi\u0146a ir sa\u0146emta!");
```

It's fairly simple to encode more strings yourself, too, assuming you've got Python 3:

```
$ python3
>>> x = "Jūsu ziņa ir saņemta!"
>>> print(x.encode('ascii', error='backslashreplace').decode('ascii'))
J\u016bsu zi\u0146a ir sa\u0146emta!
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using HTML codes for specific character in specific language

for example `Ā` has the char html code `&#257;`

about all others you can find the code [here](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm).

Comment: HTML entities within scripts are uninterpreted, so that won't work for the text of an alert.

Comment: It doesn't work, it just shows &#363; instead of the messed up character then.

Answer (score 1):

`Jūsu ziņa ir saņemta!` in utf-8 is `JÅ«su ziÅ†a ir saÅ†emta!` in iso-8559-1, so the browser is interpreting your utf-8 text as iso-8559-1. Try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in your head tag to fix this.

Comment: Already tried it, but it didn't work. The php contact form is in a seperate file from the html site, the html form points to the contact.php